# Can't access hub elements from class

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1

I had a xaml in mainpage and want to access it's elements like x:Name="D1P1" in a c# class but can't use it and get an error the name "D1P1" does not exist in the current context any idea how to access the hub elements in c# class I use FindName but it did't work

```
<Hub>
        <HubSection Width="950" x:Name="DayOneTimeHubSection" Margin="20,0,0,0">
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="180" Margin="0,0,0,-15">
                            <StackPanel Width="280" Height="160" Background="#FF253842" Margin="05,0,0,0">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="D1P1"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" LineHeight="80" TextWrapping="Wrap"  FontSize="64" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FFB0B1B2" FontFamily="Arial Narrow" Margin="0,10,0,0" />
                                <TextBlock x:Name="D1NP1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" LineHeight="64" TextWrapping="Wrap"  FontSize="64" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontFamily="DengXian" Margin="30,0" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
    </Hub>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't need to access the controls inside the `DataTemplate` from the codebehind, we bind them to properties in the ViewModel/Codebehind and to update something in the control you simply update the corresponding property in the ViewModel

```
<TextBlock x:Name="D1P1" Text="{Binding Name,Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" LineHeight="80" TextWrapping="Wrap"  FontSize="64" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FFB0B1B2" FontFamily="Arial Narrow" Margin="0,10,0,0" />
```

if you insist on accessing that control from codebehind, you could add a Loaded event handler and update the sender

```
<TextBlock x:Name="D1P1" Text="{Binding Name,Mode=TwoWay}" Loaded="D1P1_OnLoaded"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" LineHeight="80" TextWrapping="Wrap"  FontSize="64" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FFB0B1B2" FontFamily="Arial Narrow" Margin="0,10,0,0" />
```

code behind

```
 private void D1P1_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    (sender as TextBlock).Text = "Update Text";
 }
```

Comment: ok but what if i want my controls got name like t1, t2, t3, t.. and i want them access all and want to change their text what to do about this can't create onloaded method for each control???
I have used this method VisualTree but it only returns single element of the HubSection

Comment: You should create properties in your viewmodel, and bind each control's text to its corresponding property

Comment: public static DependencyObject MyFindChildByName(DependencyObject parant, string ControlName) {
int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parant);
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
var MyChild = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parant, i);
if (MyChild is FrameworkElement && ((FrameworkElement)MyChild).Name == ControlName)
return MyChild;
var FindResult = MyFindChildByName(MyChild, ControlName);
if (FindResult != null) return FindResult;}
 return null; }

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method:

```
private DependencyObject FindControl<T>(DependencyObject control, string ctrlName)
{
   int childNumber = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(control);
   for (int i = 0; i < childNumber; i++)
   {
      DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(control, i);
      FrameworkElement fe = child as FrameworkElement;
      if (fe == null) return null;

      if (child is T && fe.Name == ctrlName)
      {
         return child;
       }
       else
       {
          DependencyObject nextLevel = FindControl<T>(child, ctrlName);
          if (nextLevel != null)
             return nextLevel;
       }
    }
    return null;
 }
```

An example of use:

```
StackPanel mypanel = FindControl<StackPanel>(HubSection, "myPanel");
```

You need to pass the name of one of the top nodes (like your HubSection) and the name that you've used for the control.

I hope it's what you're talking about :D

Comment: Thanks I already use the similar technique but it was also not useful it only returns first element what i want was to get all the elments.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution and i used the following function of VisualTreeHelper to achieve it

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (depObj != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                if (child != null && child is T)
                {
                    yield return (T)child;
                }

                foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                {
                    yield return childOfChild;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and than use for each to get all of the elemetns.

```
foreach (TextBlock tb in FindVisualChildren<TextBlock>(DayOneTimeHubSection))
        {
            //YOur Logic
        }
```